# How can I get an attribute value of an XML using Node js?

Tags: node.js, xml, xmldom

I am working on a little project using Node js in which I have to access Musicbrainz API and get some data from it.

The thing is that I'm trying to get a value from the API using a URL, then gets the XML version of the resulting page and finally gets the value I want (which is "count") using the XMLDOM package for node js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmldom).

The XML looks like this and I want to get the value of count (underlined in red):
[image]

This is the function I'm using to get the value:

```
// Loading of necessary modules and creation of a new application.
var express = require("express"); 
var app = express();
var request = require("request");
var DOMParser = new (require('xmldom')).DOMParser;

// URL of the musicbrainz API.
var root_url = "https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/";

// Example: MBID = 0da580f2-6768-498f-af9d-2becaddf15e0
function getReleases(MBID){

    var releases_URL = root_url + "release-group/" + MBID + "?inc=releases"
    var count
    request({
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'my-musicbrainz-client',
        },
        url: releases_URL,
        json: false
    }, async function (error, response, body) {
    
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            var document = DOMParser.parseFromString(body);
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName("release-list")
            console.log("Release list = "+ x)

            count = x.getAttribute('count')  
            console.log("COUNT:"+ y)                                                                  
            return count
        }else{
            console.log("ERROR IN FUNCTION")
        }
    })

}
```

But the problem is that count = x.getAttribute('count') is not working as it throws UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: x.getAttribute is not a function. How is this possible since I installed XMLDOM package and the function getAttribute exists? Am I using it wrong? Is there another way to get the "count" value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns a node list so `x[0]` could be an element node for which you can call `getAttribute` if the element(s) are found. In the world of the W3C DOM APIs I think it would be safer to use `getElementsByTagNameNS` as your elements are in a namespace but I don't know that Node.js API to tell whether you need it there.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem completely!